# Leap second in Database system (Postgresql and SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, datetime

This night will be longer because of leap second: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

My impact will be minimal in my case, I don't even know if I will recive some weird data like *20150630 23:59:60*. But I have monitoring systems from both windows, linux and other systems. In worst case, I will lose one second of data.

I tested conversion of this weird data in postgresql and SQL Server. These are my results:

This select in Postgresql:

```
SELECT '20150630 23:59:60.001 UTC'::timestamptz;
```

Is returning: 2015-07-01 02:00:00.001+02

I have the same result with:

```
SELECT '20150701 00:00:00.001 UTC'::timestamptz;
```

I think this can be dangerous in critical systems, because, if this data is handled by clients, data can be stored in the wrong order, adding a second to a legitimate data.

In sql server if I try:

```
SELECT CAST('20150630 23:59:60' AS datetime)
```

It give me a conversion error. So it is not possible, in sql server, to store this data.

One gives me an error, the other just add a second. I don't like both, because it is **impossible to store events in the leap second**.

Both are recent systems. SQL server is 2014 on a window 2012 machine. Postgresql is 9.3 on redhat machine (not so update, I think a 6.2).

What if someone ask me to store this data?
I read this and some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751115/leap-second-handling-in-database

Has anyone faced this as a problem? I mean, this is just a theoretical question in my case, not a real problem (so don't waste time if you don't like theoretical questions)

**EDIT:**
Tested in Oracle 11.2, error is returned:

> > ORA-01852: seconds must be between 0 and 59
> >     01852. 00000 -  "seconds must be between 0 and 59"

Comment: FWIW on PostgreSQL 14, `SELECT '20150630 23:59:60.001 UTC'::timestamptz;` results in `ERROR:  date/time field value out of range`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a description of PostgreSQL's date handling I found on the `pgsql` mailing list [from January 2012](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/23016.1327976502@sss.pgh.pa.us):

> As best I can tell, that document is talking about issues that are
>   beyond Postgres' ken.  When you tell us a timestamp value is
>   '2012-01-30 21:13:28.097017-05', that's what we store --- whether you
>   meant it to be in TAI, UTC, UT1, or whatever is not our concern.
>   If you then ask for that date plus one day, we're going to tell you
>   '2012-01-31 21:13:28.097017-05'.  We do know about civil time zones and
>   daylight savings transitions, and will adjust such answers for those,
>   but not about leap seconds.  **There's been very little user demand for
>   leap-second-aware date arithmetic, and the difficulties with
>   extrapolating such arithmetic into the future mean that we're not
>   likely ever to try to support it.** [emphasis mine]

As [Daniel Vérité](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7119/daniel-v%C3%A9rit%C3%A9) mentioned in the comments, the bug here isn't that PostgreSQL can't store leap seconds -- it can -- it's that it can't distinguish them from the following second, and can't do maths involving leap seconds.

Also, as [dbafromthecold](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/41558/dbafromthecold) pointed out, some operating systems won't report leap seconds at all e.g. [How the Windows Time service treats a leap second](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/909614). Another example is [Google's services](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/time-technology-and-leaping-seconds.html), which apply a *leap smear*, slightly speeding up the server clocks before the leap second so as to skip over the leap second without ending up too far ahead of UTC.

So: it looks like most services are fine with a potential one-second error around leap seconds. If you need better accuracy around leap seconds, AFAICT you will need to implement your own UTC-based clock time.